# problema en template al generar <select></select> con datos del model relacionado

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Necesito de su ayuda, estoy generando `option` para un `select` apartir de los datos del modelo relacionado por `ForeignKey` a mi modelo principal desde mi template pero no puedo hacerlo.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True) 
    nombre = models.CharField("Nombre Cliente",max_length =200,blank = False,null = False)
    dui = models.CharField("D.U.I.",max_length = 15,blank = False,null = False)
    direccion = models.TextField("Dirreccion")
    telefono = models.CharField("Telefono",max_length = 15,blank = True,null = True)
    email = models.EmailField("Correo")

class Meta():
    verbose_name = 'Cliente'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Clientes'
    ordering = ['id']

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre


class Cargo(models.Model): 
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True) 
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente,on_delete = models.CASCADE,blank = False,null = False)
    fecha = models.DateField("Fecha")
    documento = models.CharField("Documento",max_length = 15,blank = False,null = False)
```

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class ClienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Cliente
        fields = ['nombre','dui','direccion','telefono','email',]

class CargoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Cargo
        fields = [
            'cliente',
            'fecha',
            'documento',
            'val_cargo',]
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class CreateCargo(CreateView):
    model = Cargo
    form_class = CargoForm
    template_name = 'cargo/crearcargo.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('listarcargo')

class UpdateCargo(UpdateView):  
    model = Cargo
    form_class = CargoForm
    template_name = 'cargo/editarcargo.html'
    success_uls = reverse_lazy('listarcargo')
```

Template:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="cliente" required id="id_cliente">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>
  {% if object_list %}
      {% for cliente in object_list.cliente.all %}
          <option value="{{ cliente.id }}">{{ cliente.nombre }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</select>
```

Y no se realmente que estoy haciendo mal por que el muestra nada el `select` alguien me puede ayudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada no existe la variable de contexto `object_list` segun tus `views` es por eso que no entra al `if` y por lo cual no funciona el `for`. De donde sacas el `object_list`?

Tambien no es necesario generar el `select` por tu propia cuenta, pues ya lo hace Django por ti, basta con poner `{{ form.as_p }}` para generarte todo el formulario.

Si quieres generar los campos por separado, pues seria asi (que creo que es lo que querias hacer):

```
{{ form.nombre_del_campo }}
{{ form.cliente }} # Asi
```

Comment: muchas gracias. fíjate que eso object_list lo vi en un tutorial

Comment: Usualmente la vista `ListView` extiende el contexto global con la variable de contexto `object_list`, para la proxima toma atencion a los tutoriales y a las vistas xd, un gusto poder ayudarte!!

Comment: gracias !!! creo fue por que soy muy nuevo con este framework